# sql injection issue

Tags: asp.net, sql, code-injection

I have the following code snippet.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT FName,LName FROM EMPLOYEE_TABLE WHERE EmployeeID = '" +TextBox1.Text + "' AND Password = '"+ TextBox2.Text +"'", con);
SqlDataReader x = cmd.ExecuteReader();

try
{ 
    if (x.Read())
    {
        name = (string)x["FName"] +' '+ (string)x["LName"];
        Session["NAME"] = name;
        Session["ID"] = TextBox1.Text;
        Response.Redirect("sample.aspx?action=On_Click");
    }
    else
    {
        errormsg.Text = "login failed.Please enter Valid UserID and Password";
        errormsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
}
catch (Exception exp)
{
    errormsg.Text = "Sorry,You dont have access to this portal.";
}
finally
{
    x.Close();
    con.Close();
}
```

Now, when i use a valid id (that exists) and password as **abc' or 'x'='x** then it logs in into the first account of the table in the database. Till this it's fine.

However when I try to debug the code, it throws an error `Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.`.

Also if it is throwing an error then why is it logging into this 1st account of the database. Note: the first account of the database has a different userid than that which i m providing.

Note: I am the developed of this application. So I'm not doing anything illegal. :)

Comment: The first question is, if you're the developer, and you're aware of SQL Injection, why aren't you at least using parameterized queries?

Comment: ya, nice question. thats bcoz i have just now learnt of sql injections and so i m trying that out on my own application. however i dont have much idea bout parameterized queries.

Comment: .net has some built in protections for some of the blatent sql injection issues(Microsoft doing what i thinks you should want it to do).  I am guessing you are running into those.  I remember when i first found out about SQL injection I ran into them too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at this part of your SQL:

```
   "' AND Password = '"+ TextBox2.Text +"'"
```

With your password, it's

```
   "' AND Password = ''x'='x'"
```

which is not the SQL you want.

Even if you are trying to do SQL injection, you have to result in valid SQL.  Usually, it's by ending the statement with a semi-colon after closing the quote.  See this:

[image]
http://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 1):

OK, to provide an answer based on the primary issue you've got (as you've stated, you're new to the SQL Injection issue).

SQL Injection is caused by dynamically building a SQL query using user input as part of the construction. The simplest solution to this in .Net is to create a parameterized query.

I think Jeff Atwood has the most complete yet concise article providing an explanation and complete example [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html)

Quoted from above link:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
conn.Open();
string s = "SELECT email, passwd, login_id, full_name " + 
  "FROM members WHERE email = @email";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(s);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", email);
SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

## The issue at hand:

The reason it's still logging into the account is because the query is still "valid".

The statement will still be executed, and the relevant record will still be returned from the database, no exception will be thrown.

The only way you will stop the login process when invalid data is provided is to validate the input before executing the query. You should **always validate user input before** sending it off to the database. If the user were to provide:

```
username'; drop table users;--
```

as the username, you would be in a **LOT** of trouble.

Comment: thank you, this is indeed helpful.I understand the bug. i guess i need to change a hell lot of stuffs in my code. 
so if i write my queries like this then is it completely safe from sql injections?

Comment: Yes, it can indeed be a big job to rewrite an application to defend against SQL injection if it hasn't been designed to do so from the start.

Answer (score 0):

The error you're encountering is a debugging error, not an actual program exception. That's why it works when you run it normally.

To remedy the error, I'd first make sure that everything is running with a Debug build. Also, make sure you're currently debugging in the function of the variable you want to inspect. Try stepping (F10) a few times past your breakpoint to refresh the context. There are a slew of other suggestions on the internet for that particular error, so if you're still having problems you might have to do some googling.

Comment: i m not concerned about the error. all i want to know that if in debug mode the app goes into the catch statement then where shud i put my Response.Redirect("sample.aspx?action=On_Click");
so that it doesnt direct into that page beofre going thru the catch block.